# Question about iterating through Pandas series with conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to generate a column that would have zeros everywhere except when a specific condition is met.

Right now, I have an existing series of 0s and 1s saved as a Series object. Let's call this Series A. I've created another series of the same size filled with zeros, let's call this Series B. What I'd like to do is, whenever I hit the last 1 in a sequence of 1s in Series A, then the next six rows of Series B should replace the 0s with 1s.

For example:

Series A

0
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
0
0...

Should produce Series B

0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1...

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
for row in SeriesA:
    if row == 1:
        continue
    if SeriesA[row] == 1 and SeriesA[row  + 1] == 0:
        SeriesB[row]=1
        SeriesB[row+1]=1
        SeriesB[row+2]=1
        SeriesB[row+3]=1
        SeriesB[row+4]=1
        SeriesB[row+5]=1
```

However, this just generates Series B full of zeros except for the first five rows with become 1s. (Series A is all zeros until at least row 50)

I think I'm not understanding how iterating works with Pandas, so any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Full(ish) code

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Python_Datafile.csv", names = fields) #fields is a list with names for each column, the first column is called "Date".
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format = "%m/%Y")
df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)

Recession = df["NBER"] # This is series A

Rin6 = Recession*0 # This is series B

gps = Recession.ne(Recession.shift(1)).where(Recession.astype(bool)).cumsum()
idx = Recession[::-1].groupby(gps).idxmax()
to_one = np.hstack(pd.date_range(start=x+pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1), freq='M', periods=6) for x in idx)
Rin6[Rin6.index.isin(to_one)]= 1

Rin6.unique() # Returns -> array([0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I think the issue you are having is that you use `freq='M'` when it needs to be `freq='MS`' when defining to_one. Again, this assumes your dates in your index are **always** the first of the month, if that's not the case you'll need to provide some examples of what the dates are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ID for consecutive groups of `1`s using `.shift` + `.cumsum`:

```
gps = s.ne(s.shift(1)).where(s.astype(bool)).cumsum()
```

Then you can get the last index for each group by:

```
idx = s[::-1].groupby(gps).idxmax()

#0
#1.0     5
#2.0    18
#Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Frorm the list of all indices with `np.hstack`

```
import numpy as np

np.hstack(np.arange(x+1, x+7, 1) for x in idx)
#array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

And set those indices to 1 in the second Series:

```
s2[np.hstack(np.arange(x+1, x+7, 1) for x in idx)] = 1

s2.ravel()
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,..
```

---

Update from your comment: Assuming you have a `Series` `s` whose indices are `datetimes`, and another `Series` `s2` which has the same indices but all values are 0 and they have the `MonthStart` frequency, you can proceed in a similar fasion:

```
s = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]*5, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='MS', periods=55))
s2 = s*0

gps = s.ne(s.shift(1)).where(s.astype(bool)).cumsum()
idx = s[::-1].groupby(gps).idxmax()

#1.0   2010-11-01
#2.0   2011-10-01
#3.0   2012-09-01
#4.0   2013-08-01
#5.0   2014-07-01
#dtype: datetime64[ns]

to_one = np.hstack(pd.date_range(start=x+pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1), freq='MS', periods=6) for x in idx)

s2[s2.index.isin(to_one)]= 1
# I check .isin in case the indices extend beyond the indices in s2
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out today and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried out what you proposed but get the following error when I get to the line "np.hstack..." : ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.

I looked up some other solutions to this problem elsewhere on stackoverflow, but none of them made sense to me. For reference, the df from which my Series A was made has months and years as row indexes (ex: 2018-08-01, 2018-07-01, etc).

Comment: I think what I need to do is somehow tell np.hstack to add months instead of just numbers like 1 and 7 to each value in idx, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @JrAnalyst are your indices `datetime` objects or just strings? If they are `datetimes` then you can try: `np.hstack(pd.date_range(start=x+pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1), freq='M', periods=6) for x in idx)` which should give you the list of months, assuming `idx` is a list of `datetimes`

Comment: @JrAnalyst See the update, let me know if that solves it.

Comment: I'm at work currently, but I'll give it a shot in the afternoon. Thank you so much for taking the time to help out btw.

Comment: Tried your method out. While everything runs perfectly, Series B still comes up filled with nothing but 0.ex: s2.unique() returns " array([0]), dtype=int64 "

Comment: Let me share the rest of the relevant code in an edit in my question. That might show where I went wrong as I still can't figure it out...

Comment: @JrAnalyst it's possible the indices of the two do not exactly match, in which case the filter `s2[s2.index.isin(to_one)]` would do nothing. Since the other should be based on the first one, why not just create it with `s2 = s*0`, which would ensure the same index?